ActionController::UnknownFormat Turbostream
I'm using rail 7 and ruby 3.2.2 version. I've created 2 ruby on rails projects, one with 7.0.0 rails version, one with 7.0.8 version. I'm learning about TurboStream but there's always an error: ActionController::UnknownFormat in UserController#active_admin
I've searched on internet but no one worked (I created this project in 7.0.0 rails version).
But the surprising thing is turbo stream work perfectly with the project in 7.0.8 rails version. I don't know why!
content file active_admin.turbo_stream.erb
<%= turbo_stream.replace @user.id do %>
  <%= render "shared/admin_btn", user: @user %>  
<% end %>

content file "_admin_btn.html.erb"
<% unless user.main_admin? %> 
        <%= button_to "delete", user_path(user), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "comfirm it" }, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
        <% if user.admin? %>
            <%= button_to "Unadmin", admin_path(user), method: :post, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
        <% else %>
            <%= button_to "Admin", admin_path(user), method: :post, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
        <% end %>
<% end %>

controller
def active_admin
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.toggle!(:admin)
    if @user.admin?
      flash[:success] = "Admin actived"
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Admin unactived"
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.turbo_stream do
        logger.debug "Responding with Turbo Stream"
      end
    end
  end

It's always "Processing by UserController#active_admin as HTML",not "as TurboStream" ,but the test project work!
i want to fix this error so bad, that's all i need to complete the project

What versions of the turbo-rails gem are you using in both projects?

the test project is 1.5.0, the error project is 2.0.5

Is that the problem Sir?
